# Derivative of the product of a matrix scalar function and a matrix with respect to a matrix

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

How to take derivative of
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial\left[\operatorname{tr}(\boldsymbol{A}^2)\cdot\boldsymbol{A}^3\right]}{\partial\boldsymbol{A}}=\,?
\end{align*}
with respect to a matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$, where $\operatorname{tr}(\cdot)$ is the scalar function of the matrix, viz., the trace of the matrix.

I tried using the derivation formula below, but this formula doesn't seem to work.

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial\left[\underset{n\times\,n}{\boldsymbol{A}}(\boldsymbol{X})\cdot\underset{n\times\,n}{\boldsymbol{B}}(\boldsymbol{X})\right]}{\partial\boldsymbol{X}}=\dfrac{\partial\left[\underset{n\times\,n}{\boldsymbol{A}}(\boldsymbol{X})\right]}{\partial\boldsymbol{X}}\left[\boldsymbol{E}_{n}\otimes\underset{n\times\,n}{\boldsymbol{B}}(\boldsymbol{X})\right]
+\left[\boldsymbol{E}_{n}\otimes\underset{n\times\,n}{\boldsymbol{A}}(\boldsymbol{X})\right]\dfrac{\partial\left[\underset{n\times\,n}{\boldsymbol{B}}(\boldsymbol{X})\right]}{\partial\boldsymbol{X}}
\end{align*}

Comment: It looks like you are trying to calculate the **gradient** of a matrix with respect to another matrix. The result will be a fourth-order tensor, which will be very awkward to handle using standard matrix notation.  What are you planning to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

$\operatorname{tr} ( (A+H)^2 ) (A+H)^3 - \operatorname{tr} (A^2) A^3 = \operatorname{tr} (AH+HA) A^3 + \operatorname{tr} (A^2)(A^2H +AHA+HA^2) + O(H^2)$ so the derivative is
$H \mapsto 2\operatorname{tr} (AH) A^3 + \operatorname{tr} (A^2)(A^2H +AHA+HA^2) $

Comment: There were two $H^2A$ terms that were supposed to be $HA^2$. Edited accordingly,

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Thanks!

Comment: no problem. I initially posted just a comment but edited because it was such a minor edit that it looked like a typo.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\b{\beta}\def\p{\partial}
\def\E{{\cal E}}\def\Eij{E_{ij}}\def\G{{\cal G}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\d{\;}
$Break the problem into a scalar piece
$$\eqalign{
 \b &= \trace{A^2} \\
d\b &= 2\trace{A\;dA} \\
}$$
and a matrix piece
$$\eqalign{
 B &= A\d A\d A \\
dB &= dA\d A\d A\;+\;A\d dA\d A\;+\;A\d A\d dA \\\\
}$$
Multiply them to obtain the function of interest
$$\eqalign{
 F &= \b B \\
dF &= B\,d\b + \b\,dB \\
  &= 2\trace{A\;dA}\,B + \b\LR{dA\d A^2+A\d dA\d A+A^2\,dA} \\
\grad{F}{A_{ij}}
  &= 2\trace{A\Eij}\,B+\b\LR{\Eij\,A^2+A\Eij\,A+A^2\,\Eij} \\
  &= 2A_{ji}B+\b\LR{\Eij\,A^2+A\Eij\,A+A^2\,\Eij} \\
}$$
where $\Eij$ is a matrix whose components are all zero except for
the $(i,j)$ component which is equal to one. Conveniently, it also
represents the gradient of a matrix with respect to
its $(i,j)$ component
$$\grad{A}{A_{ij}} = \Eij$$